# grid/table cell expanding to use available space

Tags: android

I'm having trouble getting the layout I want. 
If it's relevant the layout is used in an Adapter to fill a ListView.

This is the layout I want;
[image: layout]

The bottom half is how it should look with more available width. 
B and C expand to fill all available room. A and D remain the same width. 
BTW, the height of all sections are static, and known to me.

Here's what I've got so far;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:minHeight="50dp">

    </View>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/D"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/B" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/C"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/B"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/D" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This mostly works, but C doesn't fill the available space. It's just as wide as its content, and right aligned (attached to D's left edge).

How do I get B and C to expand?
thanks

Comment: use `weight_sum` and  `layout_weight`.

Comment: and where is A in your .XML....???

Comment: A is the ImageView

Comment: Try to set: android:layout_width="match_parent", for both your RelativeLayout and View C. Hope it help!